# Toggling multiple elements by clicking on different objects with one function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, button, toggle

I have 9 images and 9 tables. Each image acts as a "button" that will cause the table it pertains to to toggle. The tables are hidden initially with display:none, so clicking image 1 shows table 1, but clicking image 1 also makes sure tables 2-9 are hidden as well because they all show up in the same location. If the others are not hidden, then one I click on to toggle its table will appear below the one that is already showing.

The basic code to achieve this looks like so:

```
$('#img1').click(function(){
    $('#tbl2, #tbl3, #tbl4, #tbl5, #tbl6, #tbl7, #tbl8, #tbl9').hide();
    $('#tbl1').toggle('fast');
 });
```

Except that I repeat this for each image click function. What I would like to do is set up a function or something, that will allow me to greatly simplify this code since it is enormously redundant. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this to work using this code. Perhaps it will help someone else in the future.

```
$("#contianer img").click(function() {
    $('#tbl1_img, #tbl2_img, #tbl3_img, #tbl4_img, #tbl5_img, #tbl6_img, #tbl7_img, #tbl8_img, #tbl9_img').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var tblToShow = $(this).attr('id').replace('_img', '');
    $('#tbl1, #tbl2, #tbl3, #tbl4, #tbl5, #tbl6, #tbl7, #tbl8, #tbl9').addClass('hidden').removeClass('fadeIn');
    $('#'+tblToShow).toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#'+tblToShow).addClass('fadeIn');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a single class for all elements and hide them altogether

```html
<div id="tbl2" class="table"></div>
<div id="tbl3" class="table"></div>
<div id="tbl4" class="table"></div>
```

```js
$(".table").hide();
```

Shai.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to all your images, say `btn` and a `title="1"` and so on tag. Put all of your tables in a div with an id of say `info`.

Might look like this:

```
<img src="..." class="btn" title="1" />
<img src="..." class="btn" title="2" />
//...
<div id="info">
  <table id="table1"></table>
  <table id="table2"></table>
</div>
```

Now I would write the function as follows:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   //hide all the tables
   $('#info table').hide();
   //get the title
   var t = $(this).attr('title');
   //assuming a table is called "table1"
   $('#table'+t).fadeIn();
});
```

Hope this leads you in the right direction :)